# How to set binding offset in report class

Tags: margins, report

I want to add bigger margin to the left side of document for binding purposes. The default margin with report class is ~1.5 inches, but when I use the geometry to set the bindingoffset, whole layout is wrong. The side margins are shifted correct, but the whole pages is also shifted up and there is huge margin at the bottom.

MWE is here, comment out the geometry package to see the effect.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, bindingoffset=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % fix headers

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textit{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textit{#1}}{}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\parskip 1em

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\section{section}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\section{title}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

What I want is same layout as if the geometry package is not used, just with **bigger left margin**. The left margin should be 0.4 inches wider than the default.

Comment: Pass `reset` as the first option to `geometry`? You don't need to pass `a4paper` to `geometry` if you pass it to the class.

Comment: With the `reset` option the layout is still shifted upwards.

Comment: Even if you use `geometry` to specify the `headheight`? You should tell `geometry` about that for it to calculate things correctly. `reset` is *supposed* to set everything to the defaults for the class.

Comment: I don't know about the headheight, but the `vmarginratio` hinted by @eiterorm worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geometry` package loads a different page geometry for your document. Among other things, it has a default ratio of 2:3 for the top and bottom margins. The option `vmarginratio=1:1` provides equal margins at the top and bottom of the document. (Manually setting the margins will of course also change the ratio.)

```
\usepackage[a4paper, bindingoffset=0.4in, vmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following hack:

```
\usepackage[left=1.9in,right=1.4in,top=1.3in,bottom=1.3in,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
```

First I have found the values which produced the output nearly identical to output without `geometry` and then I have increased the left margin by 0.5inch.

I know it's not ideal solution but it works.